# Django : Authenticated different user models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my project, I have 2 models named **Students** and **Teachers**. These two models are a OneToOne field to **User**. 
I have 3 applications : **home** (index page, faq, about...), **teachers** (interface for teacher, manage her courses, edit profil ...) and **students** (interface for students, profil ...)

I have *one* login form (in application home), and I want to use it for log in teachers and students, and redirect to the correct application after authentication. What is the best way for doing that ? I think to create two groups (teachers and students) and assign to the correct group after registration form, and in log in form, just check the group ?

PS: Student can create an account, but for teacher, our team creates accounts, so we don't have a registration form for teachers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If relation to User table is OneToOne, you can access it from user.student or user.teacher, so you would do it...

```
def login_view(request):
   if form.is_valid():
      # get user from form
      _user = form.get_user()
      user = authenticate(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['password'])
      login(request, user)
      if hasattr(user, 'student'):
          # You'll return to student app
          return redirect('studen:home')
      # else
      return redirect('teacher:home')
```

**EDIT**

decorators.py

```
...
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
def group_required(*args):
    if args:
        def decorator(user):
            if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser:
                return True
            return user.is_authenticated() and user.groups.filter(name__in=args).exists()
    else:
        decorator = lambda x: x.is_authenticated()

    return user_passes_test(decorator)
...
```

And use it...

```
...
@group_required('student')
def home_student(request):
   # some code

@group_required('teacher', 'student'):
def common_view_for_all(request):
   # some code
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to protect access of teachers views for students, I think it's a best way to create groups and use a decorator no ?

Comment: yes, decorators bassed in groups, I'll update the answer to explain how...